# Integrating implicitly

Tags: integration

Apologies if this question sounds too primitive for advanced math folks here. It's long since I did rigorous mathematics and I need this for my research question. Basically, how do you integrate (analytically),

$$\int _{t}-\frac{sq_{t}^2(1-q_{t})}{1-sq_{t}^2}dt$$

where $q_{t}$ is a function of $t$. Can this be somehow integrated with respect to $q_{t}$? Thanks.

Comment: We probably need to know what $q_t$ is in order to know whether it can be integrated nicely (in terms of elementary function) or not. If you have $q_t=e^{t^2}/logt+ sint$ then it is probably not possible

Comment: Under some conditions, we know $q_{t}$ behaves like $e^{-t}$, but that is a neutral case which may not be realistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $u = q(t)$. Then $du/dt = q'(t) = 1/(q^{-1})'(u)$. Thus, your integral is$$\int _{t}-\frac{sq_{t}^2(1-q_{t})}{1-sq_{t}^2}dt = -s\int \frac{u^2(1-u)}{1-su^2}(q^{-1})'(u)\,du = -\int \frac{u^2(1-u)}{s^{-1}-u^2}(q^{-1})'(u)\,du.$$So, if you know the inverse function of $q$, then you're fine.

Comment: I think you missed a minus sign. Also +1 for inverse function theorem

Comment: This is super useful. Thanks. I am now trying to think what $q^{-1}_{t}$ is.

Comment: Dear Friedrich,

I need to add you on a research manuscript that I have written. May I have your email contact? Thanks!